# Granting read permission to an object in spring security ACL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, acl

I am using spring security ACL. But I have a requirement that one particular object should be accessible by all, with out the need to check for hasPermission or hasRole.

I am not sure on how to implement this, I have tried the following:

```
@NotNull
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read') or #aLong==1")
@Override
Optional<DBO_TYPE> findById(@NotNull Long aLong);
```

and also using the returnObject

```
@NotNull
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read') or returnObject.id==1")
@Override
Optional<DBO_TYPE> findById(@NotNull Long aLong);
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the following approach:

```
@NotNull
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read') or isExceptionObject(returnObject)")
@Override
Optional<DBO_TYPE> findById(@NotNull Long aLong);
```

and did the check I needed in the isExceptionObject object as below:

```
public boolean isExceptionObject(Object target) {
    if (target != null          
        && ((Optional) target).get().getId() == 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Appreciate your thoughts.